# Drag force on a cone

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, drag

I was asked to calculate the drag force on a cone with velocity 10 m/s, everything was okay until I needed to calculate the cross sectional area, the radius of the base was 0.5 m, radius of the top 0.0005 m, given that the cone falls top first, which one should I use?

Should I get some kind of an average?

Comment: Remember: using things like cross-sectional area is an approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the symmetry axis of the cone lies along the direction of travel, and if you are using the drag equation
\begin{align}
  F_\mathrm{drag} = \frac{1}{2}C_d\rho Av^2
\end{align}
to compute the drag force, then you should take $A$ to be the area of the base, namely the full area that would be obstructing your vision if you were looking at the object coming toward you.

This assertion is confirmed by Wikipedia when [it defines the drag coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient#Definition) which uses the nice term "projected frontal area;"

> The reference area depends on what type of drag coefficient is being measured. For automobiles and many other objects, the reference area is the projected frontal area of the vehicle. This may not necessarily be the cross sectional area of the vehicle, depending on where the cross section is taken. For example, for a sphere $A=\pi r^2$.

Comment: Don't forget to use the drag coefficient that corresponds to the shape of a cone.

Answer (score 0):

I say use the front-facing surface area of the cone. This would be the entire surface area minus the circular area component from the large radius.